# Translate along an orthogonal plane

Tags: calculus, geometry, vectors, linear-transformations, plane-geometry

Ok, so it's been a while since college and I'm trying to add something to our software that requires so math I'm a bit rusty on.  I'm also in software and not a math superhero, so please dumb it down a little for me.

**I need to get the equation to find a point along a plane at a constant distance away from an orthogonal vector.**

Just for reference on what I'm using this for, I have a camera looking in some general direction. I want to find a point some set distance away from the center of the camera's view on it's focal plane.

That said, this is what I have so far:

[image]

I have n=[a b c] and I have (x0, y0, z0) where x0 = longitude, y0 = latitude and z0 = altitude (above ground) in the world.

**I need a simplified formula that I can use to move any arbitrary x or y distance on that plane to get (x, y, z).**

Comment: Seems like you need (a) the equation of  the plane and (b) then find the circle of radius $\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}$ in it.  Am I reading this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The condition you are after is that the vector $(x-x_0, y-y_0, z-z_0)$ is orthogonal to $(a,b,c)$, i.e. their dot product is $0$. This boils down to:

$$a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0$$

or:

$$ax+by+cz=ax_0+by_0+cz_0$$

Comment: So my issue is that I don't know (x, y, z).  Is it valid to think about it as an offset from x0 and y0 to get the correct z0?  For instance, could I set it up like:  a(x0 + 10) + b(y0 - 10) + cz = ax0 + by0 + cz0

Comment: $(x,y,z)$ is any triplet satisfying the equation above. Because $(a,b,c)\ne(0,0,0)$, you can freely choose two of $x, y, z$ and calculate the third one from the equation. For example, if $a\ne 0$, you can freely choose *any* $y, z$ and just calculate $x=x_0-\frac{b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)}{a}$.